# StackExchange.com, Area51 and Chat.SE using old Stack Exchange dropdown menu

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, notifications, global-inbox

A day or so ago I my inbox items aren't being highlighted when they're new, but only when loaded on chat.se:

[image]

Also note the new Notifications tab is completely missing. StackExchange.com has the same issue, as does Area 51:

[image]

It seems chat.se, se.com and area51 are using an old version of the dropdown's code, while the main sites have the new version with the notification tab and proper highlighting:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have rolled out the new inbox on stackexchange.com - check it out!