# Can I see my grey notifications for all SE sites?

Tags: support, notifications

When I visit stackexchange.com I get a red notification indicator in the top left corner of the page when I have new answers or comments to read on my questions or answers on any site. When I visit specific sites I then often see grey notifications specific to that site, for badges and such. Can I see all of my grey notifications in one place somewhere?

Comment: The badge notifications are cross-site, just like the inbox ones. I'm not really sure I understand what you're asking.

Comment: @Mat I think this is a dupe of [StackExchange.com, Area51 and Chat.SE using old Stack Exchange dropdown menu](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147846/stackexchange-com-area51-and-chat-se-using-old-stack-exchange-dropdown-menu), the old dropdown doesn't have the notification tab (and has some other annoyances fixed in the new version of the dropdown)

Answer (score 5):

There is a tab called "notifications" that will list all of these.

[image]

Comment: True, however unlike the Inbox that is also available in the Network profile, the notifications don't yet have page of their own anywhere.